# Prove that the sequence $b_n = \frac{n}{1 + n}$ converges to 1 (without using limits)

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $(b_n)$ be a sequence on the Euclidean metric space $\mathbb{R}$ defined as $b_n = \frac{n}{n + 1}$. Prove that $b_n$ converges to 1 without using limits. I can't think of how to do it without using limits. I looked all over the internet but I couldn't find a formal proof example. All of them just state if it converges or diverges (which in this case is obvious).

Comment: I don't understand.  Asking what a sequence converges to is asking about a limit.  If, say, you write $b_n=1-\frac 1{1+n}$ and then remark that $\frac 1{1+n}$ converges to $0$ can I claim that I avoided lmits?

Comment: @lulu I think so, but then you would have to prove that $\frac{1}{1+n}$ converges to 0 (again without using limits) It's kind of confusing.

Comment: I think you need to provide an example of what such an argument "without limits" would look like. From my point of view, whatever one writes has got to be equivalent to showing $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=1$.  I mean, that's what "converges to $1$" means.

Comment: The dangerous way to do it is $$\frac{1+n}{n} \to \frac{1+\infty}{\infty} = \frac{\infty}{\infty} = 1$$  I say "dangerous" because the same methods will produce wrong answers in other cases.

Comment: We have the definition of convergence on a metric space $(X, d)$ is $\exists a \in X, \forall \epsilon \in (0, \infty), \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq N \Rightarrow d(a_n, a) < \epsilon$. It is siad to converge to a point A. We just have to prove that that a = 1 in this example (I think so)

Comment: That's the definition of a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it by definition. Pick $\varepsilon > 0$ and then pick $n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\frac1{n_0} < \varepsilon$, for example take some $n_0 > \frac1\varepsilon$. For any $n \in \Bbb{N}$, $n \ge n_0$ we have

$$\left|1-\frac{n}{n+1}\right| = \left|\frac1{n+1}\right| = \frac1{n+1} \le \frac1{n_0+1} < \frac1{n_0} < \varepsilon$$

and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n+1}=1$.